# How to use Ternary operator for selecting checkbox?

Tags: angularjs

How can I set/unset a checkbox by using ternary operator? This is what I have done so far but not working:

```
<input type="checkbox" "{{ (right.selected == 1)?'selected':'' }}">
```

I am using AngularJS v1.6

Comment: Are you using AngularJs or Angular 2?

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro AngularJS v1.6

Comment: Why do you have to use ternary? I mean, can you provider the context scenario?

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro As i mentioned for checkbox `selected`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply use `ng-checked` directive here, just you have to pass expression to it. No need to use Ternary at all.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="right.selected == 1">
```

---

For enabling two way binding you could use ng-model on checkbox with combination of `ng-true-value` and  `ng-false-value`

```
<input type="checkbox"
   ng-model="right.selected"
   ng-true-vlaue="1"
   ng-false-vlaue="0">
```

Comment: The only issue with this happening that if I uncheck and try to get value, it always gets '1' first time. How to get the changed state.